# How do soundcloud keep music playing on when navigating?

Tags: ajax, url, soundcloud

I'm wondering how [soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/) can play music seamlessly when navigating between pages. It's possible that they use Ajax cuz the top bar seems not to reload when navigating but i see the URL changes. Is there any way to load content using Ajax and set the URL to another one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HTML5 has introduced a new API, called HTML5 History API. You can read about using it here – http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

This API lets you update browser address bar with JavaScript, so you can change the contents of the page according to the URL. The use of AJAX doesn't really have to do with UI changes, you could check the networks tab in Chrome's developer tools to see that requests are issued with XHR.

Comment: although it's an old post, I am facing an issue with something similar. I can keep the audio playing while refreshing the page, but since I use own my audio player, the duration/event that handles the animation 0:01 - 0:02 - 0:03 ... just stops, I can't keep the data with the position the song was before refreshing. do you have an idea?

Comment: @EuChi when you say "refreshing the page", do you mean that the page is reloading, meaning that HTML is re-requested? Or do you mean that you update the contents of the page manually?

Comment: I was asking a way to reload DOM with ajax and keep audio playing, I wasn't able to keep it playing with the duration animation. Now I just put the audio out of refreshed div